# MySQL Update query with Dynamic contenct

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, I have two tables:

CATEGORY

```
----------------------------------------------
| category_name      | category_code         |
----------------------------------------------
| Suit               | SU                    |
| Western            | WE                    |
----------------------------------------------
```

PRODUCT

```
---------------------------------------------
| name             | Category     | code    |
---------------------------------------------
| xyz1             | Suit         |         |
| abc1             | Suit         |         |
| abc2             | Western      |         |
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to update code in PRODUCT, so that after updation it is will:

PRODUCT

```
---------------------------------------------
| name             | Category     | code    |
---------------------------------------------
| xyz1             | Suit         | SU/0001 |
| abc1             | Suit         | SU/0002 |
| abc2             | Western      | WE/0001 |
---------------------------------------------
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you wanna done it with 1 query and without php or other ?

Comment: mysql concat,type casting, count() substr(x from y) these are the functions you'll need if you want it ddone in sql

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it looks like you need restructure your database.  Each table should have an auto-incrementing "id" field.  This would allow the "Category" field to reference an id instead of a duplicate of the name (in case you EVER decide to change the spelling or name of that category).  Even down to your naming - if your field is IN the category table, it doesn't seem necessary to have "category_" before the "code" field name...etc

Beyond that, you're probably talking about a PHP script (or something similar) - this would allow you to repeat through each item and keep track of how many Suit codes you've added so you can increment your "code" field (I assume that's what the 0001 0002 is doing.

Off the top of my head, it'd be something like this (I'm sure it could be more streamlined/better - but hopefully this gives an idea of a way you could do it:

```
$numSU = 0;
$numWE = 0;
$products = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM product"));
foreach($products as $p) {
    $codeQuery = mysql_query("SELECT category_code FROM category WHERE category_name='".$p['Category']."'");
    $code = mysql_result($codeQuery,0,'category_code');
    if($code == "SU") {
        $numSU++;
        $numItems = $numSU;
    } else if($code == "WE") {
        $numWE++;
        $numItems = $numWE;
    }
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE product SET code='".$code."/".$numItems."'");
}
```